# Oracle tuning to lower BUFFER used

Tags: oracle, buffer, performance

I am trying to optimize one SQL that having below explain plan.

I am actually stuck at this particular line from the explain plan

```
45 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 782  Bytes: 293,832  Cardinality: 212
```

If you notice the number of Bytes is 293K, and due to it is nested loops the number of buffer used by final SQL is millions.
And it is blocked by db profile.

Any general suggestions how to reduce the number of bytes of ROW 45 above?

**Note on row 45 (from TOAD):**

*For each row retrieved by step 42, the operation in step 44 was performed to find a matching row*

Thanks a lot

```
SELECT STATEMENT  HINT: ALL_ROWSCost: 800  Bytes: 7,844  Cardinality: 1                                                                                                         
    67 SORT ORDER BY  Cost: 800  Bytes: 7,844  Cardinality: 1                                                                                                   
        66 VIEW VIEW SYS.VM_NWVW_2 Cost: 800  Bytes: 7,844  Cardinality: 1                                                                                                  
            65 HASH UNIQUE  Cost: 800  Bytes: 1,672  Cardinality: 1                                                                                             
                64 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 799  Bytes: 1,672  Cardinality: 1                                                                                          
                    61 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 795  Bytes: 1,627  Cardinality: 1                                                                                      
                        58 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 793  Bytes: 1,599  Cardinality: 1                                                                                  
                            55 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 791  Bytes: 1,571  Cardinality: 1                                                                              
                                52 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 790  Bytes: 1,537  Cardinality: 1                                                                          
                                    49 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 788  Bytes: 1,491  Cardinality: 1                                                                      
                                        46 HASH JOIN  Cost: 786  Bytes: 1,442  Cardinality: 1                                                               
                                            2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_POS_SKILL Cost: 4  Bytes: 56  Cardinality: 1                                                           
                                                1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_POS_SKILL_U2 Cost: 3  Cardinality: 1                                                         
                                            45 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 782  Bytes: 293,832  Cardinality: 212                                                            
                                                42 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 722  Bytes: 4,056  Cardinality: 3                                                          
                                                    39 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 719  Bytes: 3,909  Cardinality: 3                                                      
                                                        36 HASH JOIN  Cost: 716  Bytes: 3,795  Cardinality: 3                                               
                                                            33 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 714  Bytes: 2,318  Cardinality: 2                                            
                                                                30 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 710  Bytes: 1,662  Cardinality: 2                                          
                                                                    27 NESTED LOOPS OUTER  Cost: 706  Bytes: 1,524  Cardinality: 2                                      
                                                                        24 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 704  Bytes: 1,316  Cardinality: 2                                
                                                                            21 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 698  Bytes: 1,124  Cardinality: 2                            
                                                                                18 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 696  Bytes: 984  Cardinality: 2                          
                                                                                    15 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 694  Bytes: 892  Cardinality: 2                      
                                                                                        12 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 692  Bytes: 660  Cardinality: 2                  
                                                                                            9 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 687  Bytes: 70  Cardinality: 1            
                                                                                                6 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 5  Bytes: 49  Cardinality: 1          
                                                                                                    4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_POSTN Cost: 4  Bytes: 37  Cardinality: 1   
                                                                                                        3 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_POSTN_U1 Cost: 3  Cardinality: 1  
                                                                                                    5 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_PARTY_P1 Cost: 1  Bytes: 12  Cardinality: 1     
                                                                                                8 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_OPTY_POSTN Cost: 682  Bytes: 21  Cardinality: 1        
                                                                                                    7 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIEBEL.S_OPTY_POSTN_M1 Cost: 6  Cardinality: 821   
                                                                                            11 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_REVN Cost: 5  Bytes: 260  Cardinality: 1              
                                                                                                10 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIEBEL.S_REVN_F3 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 6          
                                                                                        14 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_PROD_LN Cost: 1  Bytes: 116  Cardinality: 1               
                                                                                            13 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_PROD_LN_P1 Cost: 0  Cardinality: 1             
                                                                                    17 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_USER Cost: 1  Bytes: 46  Cardinality: 1                   
                                                                                        16 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_USER_U2 Cost: 0  Cardinality: 1                
                                                                                20 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_POSTN Cost: 1  Bytes: 70  Cardinality: 1                          
                                                                                    19 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_POSTN_U2 Cost: 0  Cardinality: 1                   
                                                                            23 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_REVN_X Cost: 3  Bytes: 96  Cardinality: 1                             
                                                                                22 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_REVN_X_U1 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1                       
                                                                        26 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT Cost: 2  Bytes: 104  Cardinality: 1                                  
                                                                            25 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT_P1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                            
                                                                    29 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT Cost: 2  Bytes: 69  Cardinality: 1                                   
                                                                        28 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT_P1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                                
                                                                32 TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_OPTY Cost: 2  Bytes: 328  Cardinality: 1  Partition #: 46  Partition access computed by row location                                       
                                                                    31 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_OPTY_P1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                                    
                                                            35 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_SALES_METHOD Cost: 1  Bytes: 318  Cardinality: 3                                              
                                                                34 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_SALES_METHOD_U1 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1                                         
                                                        38 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_STG Cost: 1  Bytes: 38  Cardinality: 1                                                
                                                            37 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_STG_P1 Cost: 0  Cardinality: 1                                             
                                                    41 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_POSTN Cost: 1  Bytes: 49  Cardinality: 1                                                      
                                                        40 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_POSTN_U2 Cost: 0  Cardinality: 1                                               
                                                44 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_POS_SKILL_IT Cost: 20  Bytes: 2,618  Cardinality: 77                                                          
                                                    43 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIEBEL.S_POS_SKILL_IT_F2 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 20                                                     
                                        48 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT Cost: 2  Bytes: 49  Cardinality: 1                                                                
                                            47 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT_P1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                                                             
                                    51 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT Cost: 2  Bytes: 46  Cardinality: 1                                                                    
                                        50 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT_U3 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                                                                 
                                54 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_BU Cost: 1  Bytes: 34  Cardinality: 1                                                                         
                                    53 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_BU_P1 Cost: 0  Cardinality: 1                                                                      
                            57 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT Cost: 2  Bytes: 28  Cardinality: 1                                                                            
                                56 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT_U3 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                                                                         
                        60 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT Cost: 2  Bytes: 28  Cardinality: 1                                                                                
                            59 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT_U3 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 1                                                                             
                    63 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_OPTY_POSTN Cost: 4  Bytes: 450  Cardinality: 10                                                                                   
                        62 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) SIEBEL.S_OPTY_POSTN_U1 Cost: 3  Cardinality: 1
```

Comment: The explain plan is only what Oracle thinks will happen.  Are you sure that step 45 is really the problem?  And what do you mean by "number of buffer"?  How many rows does this query actually return?

Comment: If you really want to start understanding how Oracle does tuning you should invest in a copy of "Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals" by Jonathan Lewis.  It's a serious book. http://www.apress.com/9781590596364

Comment: Hi Jonearles, i am not sure as well about row 45. It is just an amateur observation. Hi APC, thanks a lot for your suggestion, i think i need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem are the following lines:

8 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE SIEBEL.S_OPTY_POSTN Cost: 682  Bytes: 21  Cardinality: 1                                                                                                            7 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX SIEBEL.S_OPTY_POSTN_M1 Cost: 6  Cardinality: 821

It is responsible for most of the costs, assuming the table/index statistics are up-to-date. Without the actual sql statement the question is why is it more expensive?

Potential problems:

- It does a full index range scan is that really necessary or can a more suitable index be created to avoid this.
- How many rows are actually read by the index scan.

Comment: hi Steve, thanks a lot for sharing your insight. Indeed, it does make sense that S_OPTY_POSTN is the cause, since it has 40 million of records. However could you let me know how  you get into that conclusion?

Comment: You have to look at the cost column. For nested loops, you need to look at both sides of the execution plan "tree". At step 8 was the biggest cost. In addition the cardinality for this step is not one and it does an index range scan.

Comment: sorry Steve, forgotten to accept that.. i accepted , thanks a lot